# Developing Wordpress-Plugin: Problems with loading .js into head and HTML-Snippet as a Shortcode

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, shortcode

I was asked to develope a Wordpress plugin for a project I am currently involved in, since I normally do Graphics and UX Design (CSS3). I am not that familiar with developing plugins for WP, although I've got quite some understanding of PHP. I've got the following code:

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: ExpButton Wordpress Plugin
* Plugin URI: https://url.de
* Description: Ein Generator des Expbuttons
* Version: 0.1
* Author: Wilko Meyer
* Author URI: http://url.com
**/

/**
* Loading js into header
**/

function add_async($url)
{
    if (strpos($url, '#asyncload')===false)
        return $url;
    else if (is_admin())
        return str_replace('#asyncload', '', $url);
    else
        return str_replace('#asyncload', '', $url)."' async='async";
}
add_filter('clean_url', 'add_async', 11, 1);


function expertbuttonjs()
{
    // Loading the JS
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( 'https://www.expert-button.de/js.js#asyncload', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-core' ), '20120208', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_scripts_with_the_lot' );

/**
*Creating Shortcode
**/

add_shortcode( 'shortcode', 'expbutton' );

function expbutton( $atts ) {

        /* Turn on buffering */
        ob_start(); ?>

        <div style="overflow:hidden;font-size:9px;height:auto;width:auto;text-align:center;margin:auto;" id="expertbuttonbg"><a target="_bl$

        <?php
    /* Get the buffered content into a var */
        $sc = ob_get_contents();

/**
*Expbutton to Shortcode
**/

add_shortcode( 'shortcode', 'expertbutton' );

function expertbutton( $atts ) {

        ob_start(); ?>

        <div style="overflow:hidden;font-size:9px;height:auto;width:auto;text-align:center;margin:auto;" id="expertbuttonbg"><a target="_bl$

        <?php

        $sc = ob_get_contents();

        ob_end_clean();

        /* Return the content as usual */
        return $sc;

}
?>
```

The purpose of this plugin is to load the `js.js` as async into the  of the page and to create an shortcode from the HTML Code below the `/* Turn on buffering */` section which can be used at wordpress sites.

Currently the code does not load the `js` into header and the shortcode which should be created does not work either and I have no Idea why. Hope someone can help me with this problem & has some clue.

Why the plugin doesn't work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, I have fixed that and added the missing content but the plugin still does not work :-/

Comment: Also the end of both `<div style="overflow:hidden;font-size:9px;height:auto; …' are missing or not? if yes update your question please. Also take the [quick tour (really fast)](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) … to learn how things are working here on S.O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some important littles changes. The html code of your buttons is incomplete (so I have try to guess). The name ou your javascript file seems to me very strange and unusual...

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: ExpButton Wordpress Plugin
* Plugin URI: https://url.de
* Description: Ein Generator des Expbuttons
* Version: 0.1
* Author: Wilko Meyer
* Author URI: http://url.com
**/

/**
* Loading js into header
**/

function add_async($url)
{
    if ( strpos($url, '#asyncload') === false )
        return $url;
    else if ( is_admin() )
        return str_replace('#asyncload', '', $url);
    else
        return str_replace('#asyncload', '', $url)."' async='async";
}
add_filter('clean_url', 'add_async', 11, 1);
```

There was a problem in the url in `wp_register_script()` function that I have corrected and in the `add_action()` too: your javascript file has to be inside your plugin root folder (I mean not in a subfolder). Also your JS file name seems to me very strange *(normally it's file finishing with* `.js` *extension and not with `.js#asyncload`)*:

```
function expertbuttonjs()
{
    // Loading the JS 
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url('/js.js#asyncload', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-core' ), '20120208', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'expertbuttonjs' );
```

Dont use `shortcode` name for shortcodes functions. The code of your buttons are incomplete in your code. Also you can't have 2 times the same name for shortcodes or functions:

```
/*
 * expbutton Shortcodes
 */

add_shortcode( 'expbutton', 'expbutton' );
function expbutton( $atts ) {

        /* Turn on buffering */
        ob_start(); ?>

        <div style="overflow:hidden;font-size:9px;height:auto;width:auto;text-align:center;margin:auto;" id="expertbuttonbg"><a target="_blank" href="'.$sc.'">Text Button</a><div>

        <?php
    /* Get the buffered content into a var */
        $sc = ob_get_contents();

/*
 *  expertbutton Shortcode
 */

add_shortcode( 'expertbutton', 'expertbutton' );
function expertbutton( $atts ) {

        ob_start(); ?>

        <div style="overflow:hidden;font-size:9px;height:auto;width:auto;text-align:center;margin:auto;" id="expertbuttonbg"><a target="_blank" href="'.$sc.'">Text Button</a><div>

        <?php

        $sc = ob_get_contents();

        ob_end_clean();

        /* Return the content as usual */
        return $sc;

}
?>
```

This should work now.